# Why would running an admin check throw a 500 error? I'm calling is_super_admin();

Tags: wp-admin, 500-internal-error

I have a plugin that I wrote. A user was experiencing compatibility problems with a theme of theirs which uses a masked dashboard to add listings on their site. If the user was logged in, and a contributor, but NOT an admin, my check for is_admin() would return true since they were technically on a dashboard page.

So.. my code checks if they are admin, then runs a series of functions. One of the checks is whether or not they have permissions to manage options. If they don't have permissions to manage options, it dies. This is a problem with the theme, so I simply wrapped my add_action tags with the following

```
if ( is_super_admin() ) {   
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'myplugin_register');
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'myplugin_menu' );    
}
```

This throws a 500 error when any admin accesses the wp-admin area of the site. I'm not sure why a simple check to see whether or not the user is a super admin would crash the site.

More info on is_super_admin() here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_super_admin

Comment: Looks like a similar issue here http://wordpress.org/support/topic/is_super_admin-returs-a-500-internal-server-error?replies=1 and I know that the function which caused the crash is located in wp_get_current_user() is located in wp-includes/pluggable.php so therefor I should be able to just include that file first, then run my check, correct?

Comment: This is my new code. Do you think it'll work? I can't test it as it's on a live website. See code here, as it looked funky in this comment http://pastebin.com/KNfur9wb

Comment: I uploaded this version to test, and again, the admin dashboard threw a 500 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your pastebin:

```
if (!function_exists('wp_get_current_user')) {
        include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/pluggable.php' );
}

if ( is_super_admin() ) {      
        add_action( 'admin_init', 'myplugin_register');
        add_action( 'admin_menu', 'myplugin_menu' );   
}
```

There is no file at `wp-admin/includes/pluggable.php`. `pluggable.php` is at `wp-includes/pluggable.php`, but I see no reason you should have to intentionally include that file. It load front and back end.

Comment: Right... my mistake. Thanks for pointing it out, and I'll try this tomorrow when the website owner is back online.   

I can't say why it's not loading automatically, it's part of the theme, and I'm assuming it's not loading all the standard admin stuff.

Comment: Errors can trigger a white screen of death depending on configuration. I am hoping that is it. :)